# How to check whether two properties objects overlaps or not in java?

Tags: java, properties

I've two properties, `property1` and `property2`

```
 Properties properties1 = new Properties();
 Properties properties2 = new Properties();

 properties1.put("A", "Apple");
 properties1.put("B", "Ball");

 properties2.put("A", "Apple");
 properties2.put("C", "Cat");
```

How can we check whether the key in `properties1` overlaps on key in `properties2`

Comment: Are you also interested in overlap of the keys, if the values are different? For example, if you do instead `properties2.put("A", "Pear")`.

Answer (score 2):

Properties derives from `HashTable`, so from `Map` too.

As with a Map you can use `properties1.entrySet()` to iterate all entries and
then for each entry you can check if it is contained in `properties2` by looking first if the key is contained and if it is contained you can compare the values:

```
    for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties1.entrySet()) {
        Object currentKey = entry.getKey();
        boolean isContained = properties2.containsKey(currentKey);
        if (isContained && entry.getValue().equals(properties2.get(currentKey))) {
            System.out.println("property equals for " + entry);
        }
    }
```

Comment: needs a check if the values are the same too. Then they 'truly' overlap

Comment: okay. just change out the == for a .equals(). The strings will not match because they aren't fetched from the string pool but instantiated with read lines.

Comment: @Tschallacka  But the question I think is not clear : "How can we check whether the key in properties1 overlaps on key in properties2" . It doesn't refer values.

Comment: True, but overlap in my opinion is not just keys, but also values. It's like a puzzle piece. And when something is ambigious, I try to go with the most strict variety. And that is: overlap = key match + value match. otherwise it's not an overlap but a value conflict.

Answer (score 2):

You may look for the intersection of both property names sets, then check which values differ :

```
Set<String> names1 = properties1.stringPropertyNames();
Set<String> names2 = properties2.stringPropertyNames();
names1.retainAll(names2); // after this line, names1 contains only common elements

// let's see which elements have different values
for(String str : names1){
    if(!properties1.getProperty(str).equals(properties2.getProperty(str))){
        System.out.println("Property "+str+" overlapping");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) extends [Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), so you can find the keys present in both objects using set intersection:

```
Set<Object> intersection = new HashSet(properties1.keySet()).retainAll(properties2.keySet());
if(intersection.isEmpty()) {
    //no overlap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance, with Java 8 :

```
    // Returns overlapping entries (K, V)
    properties1.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(properties2.get(entry.getKey())))
               .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could chack the intersection between the two `Properties` objects entry sets:

```
Set<Entry<Object, Object>> intersection = new HashSet<>(properties1.entrySet());
intersection.retainAll(properties2.entrySet());
```

`intersection` will contain the common properties, with both key name and value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it iterating on all the entries (use the `entrySet()` method) and check if they exists in the other properties.

```
boolean overlapped = properties1.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .allMatch(e -> properties2.containsKey(e.getKey()) && 
                                     properties2.get(e.getKey()).equals(e.getValue()));
```

Comment: Do you really think that with a limited set of properties(let's say 100) the overhead of a stream is worth it? Streams usually only pay off going above the 10.000's

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. This solution would also help in terms of readability.

Comment: So, in this case, "overlapped" means absolutely identical?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this method doesn't check that `e.getKey()` actually corresponds to `e.getValue()` in the `properties2`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like `allMatch` will check that `properties2` contains, rather than overlaps, `properties1`

Comment: Please apologise me if I answer to a question with another question, but if one collection overlaps another, is it the other also contained?